# C: Remove assert from production code

Tags: c, assert, production-environment

In one of the projects I'm currently working on, written in C89, I've used `assert()` statements as a way for the code to fail on my development machine when some pre-defined assumptions do not hold true. However, the code also contains some error handling code so that the program does not crash on an assertion failure in a production environment.

The project uses GNU Autotools to compile and distribute a source distribution.

Now, my question is how do I ensure that running `make dist` will remove all the assertions from my code and then generate the distribution tarball?

Comment: Can use a compiler flag `-DNDEBUG=1` to define `NDEBUG`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [assert.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h) on Wikipedia:

> Programmers can eliminate the assertions just by recompiling the
>   program, without changing the source code: if the macro NDEBUG is
>   defined before the inclusion of `<assert.h>`, the assert() macro is
>   defined simply as:
>
> `#define assert(ignore)((void) 0)`

Comment: This is the core information, but there is some extra information needed — how to ensure that the compilation for `make dist` defines `NDEBUG`, and commentary on how to ensure that all the code is rebuilt without assertions enabled, etc.

Comment: I would have thought that "how to edit makefiles from GNU Autotools" would be another topic. How to add compiler flags to GNU Autotools